# Enviar A - Windows 10

Tags: windows, w10

Estimad@s, desconozco el sitio correcto para hacer esta pregunta por lo que si este no es les pido me indiquen cuál sería. Luego de aclarar esto, les paso el parte. Como aplicación de correo predeterminada tengo el **Mozilla Thunderbird** con la última versión instalada **115.7.0 (64-bit)**.

Cuestión que, por lo general yo hacía click derecho sobre un archivo, ponía Enviar a y seleccionaba **Thunderbird** y me abría un nuevo mail **con el archivo seleccionado adjuntado.** Pero, por motivos que desconozco ya no puedo hacerlo.

Estuve realizando modificaciones dentro de las propiedades del archivo que se encuentra en la carpeta SendTo al punto que el archivo quedó con esta propiedad de destino:

```
"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe" osint -compose attachment=""
```

Con esto solo he conseguido que me abra un nuevo mail **y me "adjunte"** lo que sería la ubicación del archivo seleccionado. En el nuevo mail sale como archivo adjunto lo siguiente: **c\users\usuarios\descargas\prueba.png**

¿Alguien tiene idea de cómo solucionarlo?

Comment: Se te replico la pregunta, por eso te borre una..

Comment: Y si, esto no es un problema de programacion.. es mas.. casi que deberias preguntarlo en los foros de thunderbird... a veces funciona, desinstalando y volviendo a instalar... no reinstalando... si no, de cero...

Comment: Botón derecho a un archivo y "Enviar a" -> "Destinatario de correo" se abre una ventana de un nuevo correo en Thunderbird con el archivo adjuntado. **Importante** - Para que esto funcione, debes asegurarte que Thunderbird sea el [cliente de correo predeterminado](https://www.google.com/search?q=thunderbird+default+mail+client+windows+10), Menú "Opciones" - "General" - "Integracion con el sistema" botón -> "Comprobar ahora".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma en la que pude solucionarlo fue creando un archivo .bat que se encarga de obtener el nombre y la ruta del archivo, luego seteo la ruta del programa Thunderbird y para finalizar ejecuto el comando que se encarga de crear un nuevo mail adjuntando el archivo, saludos!

```
@echo off
set strfile="%1"
echo %strfile%

set strurlcompleta="C:\Program Files\Mozilla Thunderbird\"
echo %strurlcompleta%

cd %strurlcompleta%
start thunderbird.exe osint -compose attachment=%strfile%
exit
```